# Create online customised UI for Spring application

Tags: spring-mvc, user-interface, web-applications, user-interaction

I am basically a java developer and I am not so good in creating the best user interface, 
Is there any online user interface (like drag and drop)which helps me to build best UI and I can integrate to Spring application.

Comment: Have you tried using things like invisionapp.com ? It helps you create a prototype, or http://scripteden.com/builder/bootstrap/

Comment: @gkmohit Ya its good, Looking for more stuff like popup, dropdown on click etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing? There is some form of drag and drop, but like all GUI customization it requires user adjustments. Here is a link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: Swing does not work for me :( , I need more stuff like bootstrap views